# fpdf output, is it possible to save my output to a specific accounts google drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, fpdf

I just want to know if it is possible to save the fpdf output into the google drive of a specific account.
I must also be able to give password and username of my google account for this to happen.

```
$pdf->Output("Enter google drive path here",'S');
```

Comment: FPDF itself can't do that.

Comment: Is it possible to use google drive API to do this?